# Winrt - Binding values to Latitude and Longitude on Bing Map

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have this DataTemplate that contains a Map

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyMeetingsWithMapSquares">


        <Grid Width="350" Height="290" DataContext="{Binding}" >
            <StackPanel >
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0,1"  >
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0072C6" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF008FD4" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </StackPanel.Background>

                <Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#0166a0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="10,0,10,0">
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">

                            <Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,16,0,0" Text="{Binding MyMeetingSquareDayNumber}" Width="40" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="33" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,16,0,0" Text="{Binding MyMeetingSquareMonthText}" Width="60" FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular" FontSize="33" FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,16,0,0" Text="{Binding MyMeetingSquareYearText}"  Width="60" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="33" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" Text="Business meeting" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyMeetingSquareDayHour}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#0166a0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="10,0,10,0">
                        <StackPanel >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyMeetingSquareSummary}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="16" Margin="0,10,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#0166a0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="10,0,10,0">
                            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
                                <GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle2}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyMeetingsSquareUsers}"  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource meetingSelector}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0"  SelectionMode="None" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                </GridView>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Height="150" DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <Maps:Map Tag="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLat}"  Margin="0,10,0,0"  DoubleTappedOverride="Map_DoubleTappedOverride" ShowBreadcrumb="False" Height="150" ShowNavigationBar="False"  ShowScaleBar="False" ShowTraffic="False" Width="350" Credentials="AnZKLHgAfKSwa5BAB2Kr-g8KENJBm1US3txxxxxxzCDUAgxhgJZVXyUgRIwM" ViewChanged="Map_ViewChanged" >
                            <Maps:Map.Center>
                                <Maps:Location Latitude="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLat}" Longitude="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLng}"/>
                            </Maps:Map.Center>
                        </Maps:Map>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Im trying to bind values to its latitude and longitude, but for some reason they are allways 0. i tried binding one of the values to the Map tag and it worked, the tag was 49.597378 but the latitude was 0.

how do i pass the values to the map lat and lng ?

**EDIT**

so i've changed some things on my code and added a pushpin

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Height="150" DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <Maps:Map Tag="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLat}" DataContext="{Binding}" ZoomLevel="5"  Margin="0,10,0,0"  DoubleTappedOverride="Map_DoubleTappedOverride" ShowBreadcrumb="False" Height="150" ShowNavigationBar="False"  ShowScaleBar="False" ShowTraffic="False" Width="350" Credentials="AnZKLHgAfKSwa5BAB2Kr-g8KENJBmxxxxxxyOCEwbJzCDUAgxhgJZVXyUgRIwM" ViewChanged="Map_ViewChanged" >
                            <Maps:Map.Center>
                                <Maps:Location Latitude="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLat}" Longitude="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLng}"/>
                            </Maps:Map.Center>
                            <Maps:Map.Children>
                                <Maps:Pushpin >
                                    <Maps:Pushpin.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Pdf/edit.png"/>
                                    </Maps:Pushpin.Background>
                                    <Maps:MapLayer.Position>
                                        <Maps:Location Latitude="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLat}" Longitude="{Binding MyMeetingSquareLng}" />
                                    </Maps:MapLayer.Position>
                                </Maps:Pushpin>
                            </Maps:Map.Children>
                        </Maps:Map>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
```

The pushpins appear in the correct position, but the map center continues to go to point 0 0  , it doesnt read the binded values for some reason.

Comment: not sure but you might want to remove the "credentials" tag, looks like it contains sensitive info

Comment: my guess would be that the value you're trying to pass is not in the correct format. What format is `MyMeetingSquareLat`

Comment: @roryok my credentials aren't those :p i edited the letters

Comment: public string MyMeetingSquareLat , its a string

Comment: Besides that the property type should be `double`, you should also note [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/436fc737-19c8-4832-a1c4-368f88063616/anyway-to-make-a-binding?forum=bingmapswindows8).

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a string (as you said in the comments) to the `Latitude` property of `Maps:Location`. However `Maps:Location` expects a `double` for this value.

You need to convert this value into a double with the following code:

```
Double.Parse(myStringValue);
```

If the value `MyMeetingSquareLat` can't be changed to a string itself, then add another property like this, and bind to it instead:

```
public Double MyMeetingSquareLatDouble
{
    get
    {
        return Double.Parse(this.MyMeetingSquareLat);
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed my variables to doubles, it still doesnt work :\

Comment: try stepping through with the debugger and check what the double values actually are at time of binding

Comment: latitude is 49.597378 and longitude is 6.1177072000000408

Comment: i eventually set the center of map in code behind using the coordinates of the pushpin, but im still confused why the binding didn't work eheh